# How I can translate this string? - Android

Tags: android

ı have this code on my app:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MaterialTabListener {
MaterialTabHost tabHost;
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
private String[] tabs = {"Home","Category","Favourite"};
Toolbar toolbar;
String strMessage;
private AdView mAdView;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;
```

I wanna translate from rescourse this code:

```
private String[] tabs = {"Home","Category","Favourite"};
```

But when I put R.string.menu_home, It's gives some errors of me. Someone can help me pls?

Comment: Show us your `strings.xml` file please

Comment: Simply put your string arrays in the corresponding `values` folders.

Comment: I know this. AS gives me this error: http://i.hizliresim.com/j88ngn.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string-array
            name="string_array_name">
            <item>Home</item>
            <item>Category</item>
            <item>Favourite</item>
        </string-array>
    </resources>
```

To pull this out in a String array

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] tabs = res.getStringArray(R.array.string_array_name);
```

Comment: Bro I tired everytihng. getString(R.string.menu_home) or etc codes. It's ok Android Studio don't gives me an error I can build to APK also but when I try to launch application it's stopping by self. I'm getting to be crazy because of this shit error

Comment: No body know some solution?

Comment: did you look at the logs to check what the error is?